# Strange RAM uses ,Too much buff/cache

Tags: ram, cache

I have noticed that `system-monitor` on Gnome is showing me `60%` uses of Memory

[An Image from gnome system-monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk1Ue.png)

So I typed `top` command and I found that my used RAM should be really smaller than what is shown to me.

```
top

top - 20:00:34 up  1:38,  1 user,  load average: 0.36, 0.46, 0.53
Tasks: 289 total,   1 running, 287 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.7 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.4 id,  1.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16306128 total,   421596 free,  7371692 used,  8512840 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  3904508 total,  3231948 free,   672560 used.  1011392 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
17090 alizeyn   20   0 1340004 369532 111352 S  27.6  2.3   0:25.38 firefox     
 8224 root      20   0  310064 106816  63532 S  11.3  0.7   6:10.01 Xorg        
 8557 alizeyn   20   0 2211828 341004  88540 S   4.7  2.1   4:43.26 gnome-shell 
17205 alizeyn   20   0  631312  40912  27756 S   3.7  0.3   0:00.65 gnome-term+ 
11816 alizeyn   20   0 7250408 3.342g 179900 S   3.0 21.5  13:38.84 qemu-syste+ 
 8533 alizeyn    9 -11  501320  20900  17364 S   2.7  0.1   2:27.52 pulseaudio  
 5647 root      20   0    4400   1296   1204 S   1.3  0.0   0:22.22 acpid       
 9621 alizeyn   20   0 7430968 1.110g  39928 S   1.3  7.1  13:19.76 java        
16272 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.0  0.0   0:00.33 kworker/6:0 
 5465 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   0:53.51 irq/16-iwl+ 
14851 alizeyn   20   0  740124  44752  31172 S   0.7  0.3   0:10.98 vpnui       
17229 alizeyn   20   0   41932   3732   3036 R   0.7  0.0   0:00.06 top         
 7863 root      20   0  275760  15900  13416 S   0.3  0.1   0:09.13 vpnagentd   
 7878 root      20   0  325500  28536  21864 S   0.3  0.2   0:00.23 apache2     
    1 root      20   0  185312   5936   3972 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.59 systemd     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.46 ksoftirq
```

and finally by `free -m` I found that Yes! my used RAM is very smaller but

there is huge data on `buff/cache`

output of `free -m`:

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15923        7294         156        6537        8472        1695
Swap:          3812         391        3421
```

I know that the cache is not important and I haven't be worry about but 
I can't see the right statistics from system-monitor and it's the problem that bother me.
Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: The huge value is under `shared`... (which is included in `buffers/cache`). What is consuming 6.5 GB of temporary files?

Comment: @AlexP I'm not sure that I understand you, but if you mean that `buffer/chache` is not a problem because they're temp files , the problem is :** gnome system-monitor shows me a wrong statistics **, I use it a lot

Comment: There is a problem, and it is the `shared` column. That column usually corresponds to files created on memory-based temporary file systems. They are supposed to be small.

Comment: @AlexP right, as `free` command shows buffer/cache is huge

Comment: Ali, the number under `buffers/cache` includes the number under `shared`. It is expected to have a certain amount of memory allocated to buffers and cache; what I find surprising the large amount given to `shared`.

Comment: @AlexP So I have to reduce this is allocated memory somehow ?

Comment: You have to find out _who_ is using it.

Comment: The fourth 'top' line says the kernel is using 8.5 GB of RAM for cache and buffers to speed stuff up

Comment: If apps need more RAM the kernel gives back some cache. Nothing to worry about

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix but system-monitor shows me full RAM as you can see on the picture, and it use swap ( I changed my swapiness to 20 so after 80% it use swap ) if the Kernel gives it back why it uses swap